# Getting data from multiple sheets into a variable of defined for another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have come across a case where I want to get the data from multiple sheets into a variable in another sheet in VBA. I want to append that variable data into a Textfile.

I dont want to export the entire data into a textfile, I only want to export the data in a particular range.

So right now for each sheet I have a variable that contains required data from each worksheet and I want to send data from variable from each sheet to a function defined in a Master Sheet.

Lets say I have a variable `s1` in sheet 1 containing some data. I want that variable data to be assessable in another sheet.

How can I meet the above requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you would like to control it from the MasterSheet, you have declare the variable as Public on the Sheets, then Give some value for the text. You can get the values from the MasterSheet:

On `Sheet1`

```
Public s1 As String

Sub giveValue()
    s1 = "Hello from Sheet1"
End Sub
```

On `Sheet2`

```
Public s1 As String

Sub giveValue()
    s1 = "Hello from Sheet2"
End Sub
```

Access using the MasterSheet
on `MasterSheet` or any modul

```
Sub AssessSheetVariables()
    Debug.Print Sheet1.s1
    Debug.Print Sheet2.s1
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Hello from Sheet1
Hello from Sheet2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `s1` in worksheet `Sheet1` you can pass it to a `MasterSheet` function:

On `Sheet1`

```
Sub Example()
Dim s1 As String
    s1 = "Hello"
    MasterSheet.AssessString s1
End Sub
```

On `MasterSheet`

```
Sub AssessString(s As String)
    ' do some stuff
End Sub
```